# mouse handler in opencv for large images, wrong x,y coordinates?

Tags: opencv, mouseevent

i am using images that are 2048 x 500 and when I use cvShowImage, I only see half the image. This is not a big deal because the interesting part is on the top half of the image. Now, when I use the mouseHandler to get the x,y coordinates of my clicks, I noticed that the coordinate for y (the dimension that doesnt fit in the screen) is wrong.

It seems OpenCV think this is the whole image and recalibrates the coordinate system although we are only effectively showing half the image.

I would need to know how to do 2 things:
- display a resized image that would fit in the screen

- get the proper coordinate.

Did anybody encounter similar problems?

Thanks!

Update: it seems the y coordinate is divided by 2 of what it is supposed to be

code:

```
EXPORT void click_rect(uchar * the_img, int size_x, int size_y, int * points)
{
CvSize size;
size.height = size_y ;
size.width = size_x;

IplImage * img;
img = cvCreateImageHeader(size, IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);
img->imageData = (char *)the_img;
img->imageDataOrigin = img->imageData;

img1 = cvCreateImage(cvSize((int)((size.width)) , (int)((size.height)) ),IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);

cvNamedWindow("mainWin",CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE); 
cvMoveWindow("mainWin", 100, 100);

cvSetMouseCallback( "mainWin", mouseHandler_rect, NULL );

cvShowImage("mainWin", img1 );

//// wait for a key
cvWaitKey(0);

points[0] = x_1;
points[1] = x_2;
points[2] = y_1;
points[3] = y_2;

//// release the image
cvDestroyWindow("mainWin");
cvReleaseImage(&img1 );
cvReleaseImage(&img);
}
```

Comment: Windows, Linux or Mac OS X and OpenCV version are you using?

Comment: i am using windows, using microsoft visual c++ 2008 express

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am having the same problem with OpenCV 2.1 using it with Windows and mingw compiler. It took me forever to find out what was wrong. As you describe it, cvSetMouseCallback gets too large y coordinates. This is apparently due to the image and the cvNamedWindow it is shown in being bigger than my screen resolution; thus I cannot see the bottom of the image.

As a solution I resize the images to a fixed size, such that they fit on the screen (in this case with resolution 800x600, which can be any other values:

```
// g_input_image, g_output_image and g_resized_image are global IplImage* pointers.

int img_w = cvGetSize(g_input_image).width;
int img_h = cvGetSize(g_input_image).height;

// If the height/width ratio is greater than 6/8 resize height to 600.
if (img_h > (img_w*6)/8) {
    g_resized_image = cvCreateImage(cvSize((img_w*600)/img_h, 600), 8, 3);
}
// else adjust width to 800.
else {
    g_resized_image = cvCreateImage(cvSize(800, (img_h*800)/img_w), 8, 3);
}

cvResize(g_output_image, g_resized_image);
```

Not a perfect solution, but works for me...

Cheers,
Linus

Answer (score 1):

You should create a window with the CV_WINDOW_KEEPRATIO flag instead of the CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE flag. This temporarily fixes the problem with your y values being wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I use OpenCV2.1 and visual studio C++ compiler. I fix this problem with another flag CV_WINDOW_NORMAL and work properly and returns correct coordinates, this flag enables you to resize the image window.

```
cvNamedWindow("Box Example", CV_WINDOW_NORMAL);
```

Answer (score 0):

How are you building the window? You are not passing CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE to cvNamedWindow(), are you?

Share some source, @Denis.

Comment: please note that i've tried both with and without the CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE option and it gave me the same results.